# Telerik Scheduler control In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-scheduler

I am new in MVC ..In our new mvc application i have to use Telerik RadScheduler control. If any one knows, please give a brief description about this..
Thanks

Comment: sinoy - quick bit of advice. you've left a few previous questions unanswered and/or in limbo. you should resolve those and i'm sure you'll get good response moving fwd. best..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinoy,

I think the online resources from Telerik should answer most of your questions:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

pretty thorough, give it a sneek peek - cheers

also, at present, Radscheduler isn't supported in mvc, see:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/example-of-radscheduler-in-mvc-application.aspx